# How can I create a 2D array of 2D char arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a 2D array [3][3] ; each element should be a 3x3 character array
How can I accomplish this in java?

Answer (score 2):

That seems complicated … but still, this is how:

```
char[][][][] board = new char[3][3][3][3];
```

This sounds like a Sudoku board. It'd be much, much easier if you defined a 9x9 2D `char` array, taking care of iterating over the right zones whenever you have to (simply by controlling the looping variables). Trust me, thinking in terms of a 4D array is gonna be a headache.

Answer (score 1):

Create Array Class:

```
public class 2DChar {

    private char[][] elem = new char[3][3];

    //getters, setters...     

}
```

Create Array of Array elements:

```
2DChar[][] 2dCharArray = new 2DChar[3][3];
```

Initialise it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2dCharArray.lenght(); i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 2dCharArray[i].lenght(); j++) {
      2dCharArray[i][j] = new 2DChar();
      //set value, etc...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also work:

```
Object[][] array = new Object[3][3];
char[][] subArray = new char[][] {{'a','b','c'},
                                  {'d','e','f'},
                                  {'g','h','i'}};
array[0][0] = subArray;
// initialize remaining arrays here
```